# Best practice to store images in xml?

Tags: c#, xml, database

I am writing a single exe file application that can load and save data files (txt, csv, xml and json), the user can choose a custom image, save it in a data file and send the file to another user who should then be able to open it and see the image.

Since I want the application to be user friendly and easy to use (I know that's repetition :) ) I want it to work with a single data file, instead of having user1 send all his images to user2 so that user2 can see them, so the way I see it - storing the image in the file is innevitable. Here comes the question what would be the best practice of storing the image?

I'm guessing a byte array is better than a string?

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate, as the other question asks how to store an image in XML, while I'm asking for the best practice to do so, while at the same time wondering if that's really the only way in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a base64 encoded string, since it uses less space then hex encoding. Almost every programming language should have a library to convert from a stream or byte array to base64 and the other way around